# Does DolphinDB have any functions to calculate the min value of each set ranging from the data in each position to the last data?

Tags: dolphindb

I have a data set A and the desired output is as set B indicates.

I'd like to obtain a set of min values from several subsets within set A. The first subset starts from the first data position to the last data position in set A. The second subset starts from the second data position to the last data position and the rest subsets follow the same pattern. The output dataset should include all the min values.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You may use function `ftmmin` in DolphinDB to obtain the result:
[image]

Or you can adopt ftmmin to encapsulate a function to further facilitate the calculation:

```
def fmmin(x){len = size(x); return ftmmin(1..len, x, len)}
```